# Open div on mouseover and keep it open while clicking link in the same div

Tags: jquery, css, events, mouseevent

So, I am making a tab layout. Tabs are getting bigger on mouseover and smaller on mouseout and I have a link in each tab which opens div under. The problem is that when I put my mouse on this link, tab gets smaller, because mouse kind of leaves this tab.
So, my question is- how can I put these two together so that it works more smooth and clothes only when the mouse actually leaves that area?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.slice').mouseenter(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('widthA', $this.css('width')).stop().animate({'width': '250px'}, 400);
        }).mouseout(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.stop().animate({'width': $this.data('widthA')}, 200);
        });

    $(".tabLink").click(function(){
        $('.projectTab').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).attr('name')).show();   
    });

});    
</script>
<style>
    .slice { color: gray; width: 1%; }
    li { background: yellow; }
    .sliceWrap { margin: 0; height: 70px; padding: 0px; display: table; width: 100%; }
    .sliceWrap  ul { margin: 0; height: 70px; padding: 0px; display: table; background: #ccc; width: 100%; } 
    .sliceWrap li { list-style: none; padding: 0px; width: auto; display: table-cell; white-space: nowrap; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #c00; }
    .slice a { cursor: pointer; }
    .projectTab { display: none; height: 150px; width: 150px; margin: 0 auto; }
</style>

<div class="sliceWrap">
    <ul>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="first">1</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="second">2</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="third">3</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="fourth">4</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="fifth">5</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="sixth">6</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="seventh">7</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="eighth">8</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="ninth">9</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="tenth">10</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="eleventh">11</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="twelfth">12</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="thirteen">13</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="fourteen">14</a></li>
        <li class="slice"><a class="tabLink" name="fifteen">15</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="projectTab" id="first">1</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="second">2</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="third">3</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="fourth">4</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="fifth">5</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="sixth">6</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="seventh">7</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="eighth">8</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="ninth">9</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="tenth">10</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="eleventh">11</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="twelfth">12</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="thirteen">13</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="fourteen">14</div>
<div class="projectTab" id="fifteen">15</div>
```

Here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/Lrozwrbn/)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `mouseout` to `mouseleave`. Mouseleave event triggers only when the mouse leaves the element.

If you see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/), it's explained clearly.

> The mouseleave event differs from mouseout in the way it handles event
>   bubbling. If mouseout were used in this example, then when the mouse
>   pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseleave event,
>   on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the
>   element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the Outer element, but not
>   the Inner element.

JS code

```
$('.slice').mouseenter(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('widthA', $this.css('width')).stop().animate({'width': '250px'}, 400);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.stop().animate({'width': $this.data('widthA')}, 200);
});
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/Lrozwrbn/2/)

Comment: I am trying this out and have a question: how can I do the same thing, but using 'click' event for div animation and 'hover' for displaying hidden divs?

Comment: You need to write the click and hover event separately. On click call the animation and on hover do the show/hide. I hope I got your question right.

Comment: I get that I need to write those seperatly (as it is in my sample). I guess I asked wrong: my question is- how can I make the accordion work on click? Now there are two events - mouseenter and mouseleave, but click is just one. I saw somwhere 'odd click' and 'even click' option, but my knowledge is not strong enough to do that.

Comment: I am not sure if I got your question right. [Is this what you wanted?](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/Lrozwrbn/4/). Eg. Clicking on "2" will show the respective div and clicking again will hide it.

Comment: No. I wanted these little slices to get bigger on click and smaller, when different slice is clicked! Thank you so much for even thinking about this!

Comment: Ok here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/Lrozwrbn/6/). I have used `selected` class when clicked so the `mouseover` and `mouseout` will check if the element has got `selected` class.

Comment: Thank you! This works fine. There is just one small thing- when you click every slice the first time, it works perfectly, but if you go back to a slice, the first click on it makes it bigger and only the second click opens the div underneath it. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Aah, I had used the old fiddle for the solution. I was adding 'expand' and 'collapse' before, just removed it. [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/Lrozwrbn/11/)

Answer (score 1):

Add an ambiguous class to your divs (don't remove the ones who have currently), for example Slicerino and use it as the selector, so everytime you have your mouse over them, it gets bigger!

Hope it solves your problem!